# PLSQL group by with range table joining is showing proper count

Tags: date, plsql, group-by, count

Hi I am joining a table with range of 1 month days, to get the per day count based of join table(base table).

For that I using left outer join to get count of per day.
 where my base table is as shown below (table name REGISTRIERUNG]

[image]

And I have create range of one month using below query

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 AS daterange
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE ROWNUM <=
            TO_DATE ('30-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
          - TO_DATE ('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
          + 1;
```

[image]

but I getting count 1 for date where there now record matching with range table 
instead of 0 count.

I am using below query for final result.

```
SELECT TRUNC (a.daterange), COUNT (a.daterange)
    FROM    (SELECT TO_DATE ('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1
                       AS daterange
               FROM all_objects
              WHERE ROWNUM <=
                         TO_DATE ('30-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                       - TO_DATE ('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                       + 1) a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            REGISTRIERUNG b
         ON TRUNC (a.daterange) = TRUNC (b.MODIFIKATIONZEIT)
GROUP BY TRUNC (a.daterange)
ORDER BY TRUNC (a.daterange) ASC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not count rows based on the column that is **always** populated (in your query `a.daterange` is always populated because this column from your inline view has all the dates in a month). Rather, you should count number of rows from the table that is outer-joined to the inline view with generated dates. Note that `count` function will not take into account rows that have `null` value in the column `modifikationzeit`.

For instance:

```
select a.daterange,
       count(b.modifikationzeit)
  from (select to_date('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + level - 1 as daterange
          from dual
       connect by level <= to_date('31-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') -
                           to_date('01-10-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + 1) a
  left outer join registrierung b
    on a.daterange = trunc(b.modifikationzeit)
 group by a.daterange
 order by a.daterange;
```

I have removed unnecessary `trunc's`, and converted query from `all_objects` to the one that uses `connect by` clause. I also fixed date generation for October - it has 31 days, not 30 as per your example.